# Detection of multiple similar stones on 2d Images algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, object, computer-vision, detection

So we have an image with say clearly visible to human eye stones (and some noise, here it is grass):

[image: stones on dirt]

As you can see stones have quite similar texture (except black ones), and quite similar verge. I wonder if there is any popular algorithm for detection of number of stones, and there borders on images like this?

---

What have I tried - **K-means**:

So first we could do something like [Bilateral Blur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilateral_filter) (aka surface blur) and get less nozy image (some Pixel Bender code [here](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&loc=en_us&extid=1789025)):

[image]

On that we could do some K-means clustering ( Octave/Matlab code and logic example [here](http://openclassroom.stanford.edu/MainFolder/DocumentPage.php?course=MachineLearning&doc=exercises/ex9/ex9.html)  and it takes really lot time to converge) like I've got here:

[image]

And as you can see K-Means do not solve the problem at hand - they tend to join objects not keep tham sepparated.

---

In case we could at least find all stones in general (not there borders\verge but at least few points for each stone alike `there are 2 stones on image: A has points x1,x2,x3, B has points x4,x5` ) than we could perform something like [Allan D. Jepson’s "Robust Boundary Detection With Adaptive Grouping"](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~jepson/segmentation/pdf/POCV_adaptive.pdf) and that would be a solution for me... But how to detect different stones?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In such a case, prior to applying any algorithm, you have to pre-process the image, in order to get rid of unwanted noise and to put your desired subject into focus.

Since the noise (grass) is thin, and the stones are well separated, if all your images are like this, there are some steps that could consistently yield good results.

You may start by converting it to gray, than removing high frequency noise - which is, remove the details, and then threshold it to black and white - or apply a low pass filter - the grass will mostly go away.

You may then apply a morphological opening filter to thin the connections betwwen the stones so that most get separated, and then just count the connected components.

A library such as "leptonica" (http://www.leptonica.com/)   can help you with most filters if you are using C or Python for your work.

I attached a sample of how your image might like - although I got to this manually fiddling with the image in the GNU Image Processing Program (GIMP) [image: pre-processed stones image file]

and a copy of it, witha superposition of your original image [image]

Comment: quite intresting if [A Real Time Morphological Snakes Algorithm](http://www.ipol.im/pub/algo/abmh_real_time_morphological_snakes_algorithm/) would be capable to extend borders back from morphological opening ones... and it would be probably much faster than k-means...

Comment: because on 4 points given manually it [works quite well](http://www.ipol.im/pub/demo/abmh_real_time_morphological_snakes_algorithm/result?key=F66017BD34751D5F871D5F19007F1921#)